# Best way to preload a page with images for best user experience

Tags: php, jquery, caching, preloader

I am creating a website where there are many pages to scroll through using next and prev buttons. I started by creating a java slideshow, but then there where many problems creating hashtags and subsequent social like buttons for each image. I ditched that framework because 1) users with JS turned off could not enjoy the images at all and 2) it was a pain in my ass.

What I have now is a collection of many pages with an image on it where each next button has a link to the next page.

What is the best way to make the page transition look like nothing changes except for a preloaded image (header, asides and footer don't 'blink')? Much like funnycatpix.com/_pics/Cat_Lookout.htm

Keep in mind I don't want to use iframes or ajax and I want to keep jquery to a minimum. I have PHP 5 on my server, as well.

Do I cache the images of the next page? Do I cache the entire next page? Do I change the header controls to extended cache lifetime?

Comment: Java slideshows rock my world !

Comment: Java slideshows are cool, but I have hundreds of images that need their own url, social like buttons with og tags and commenting.

Comment: @doobada - and you're sure not the least bit confused about java and javascript ?

Comment: @adeneo - I'm sure I am more than a bit confused...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code I can't offer a lot of specific help.  You can cache an image very easily just by using this:

```
$("<img>").attr('src', imageSource);
```

This can be used to preload images, so what you can do is preload the images that will appear on the "next" page when the page loads or each time "next" is clicked.

Comment: I know of this code for preloading images, but what I am trying to do is have the header, asides and footer remain constant (no blinking) when the 'next' button is clicked.

Comment: @doobada I assume the 'next' button is a link to the next image.  What you can do is prevent the default link behavior and change the main image source to the next image instead.  This either requires ajax to get the next image source, or you can preload X number of next image sources.

Comment: The 'next' button is a link to another page with specific meta og tags and information about that specific photographer. I already did what you suggest, but I am not happy with it. There has to be a better way to make the transition between pages seemless...?

Comment: @doobada which did you do? I gave you two options.

Comment: I will use the preloading code to preload the 'next' image. But the issue I am having is making the header and footer look like they don't reload.

Comment: @doobada the only way to prevent that is to not reload the page (i.e. disable the link behavior of the next button)

Comment: I already built the site similar to your ajax solution, but was not happy with it.

Comment: ah, so it is not possible to prevent the 'blinking' without ajax or some other framework...? Thanks

Comment: @doobada you don't need ajax if you have all of the images you need already loaded into the page initially.  Then you can just keep changing the image source

Comment: Then it's a pain and didn't always work great with hundreds of images to give each image a url and it's own meta og tags. Thanks for the suggestion, though, @Explosion Pills